# How to avoid warning "client not handshaken client should reconnect" in socket.io?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have nodejs application in my project on php. The main aim of it is to send messages about new events to client.

I use for it socket.io and redis pub/sub. I have one redis channel. For example when user send email to other user on a site php code publish this message to redis channel. Nodejs app subscribes to this redis channel and send new message to client. On server I have 16 core cpu, 2.4GHz, 16GB RAM and nodejs v0.10.18. Avg cpu using is 9%. Avg connections to nodejs are 1500. And in my node log I very often can find warning:

> warn  - client not handshaken client should reconnect

After this warning clients disconnected and didn't get new messages.
What can be reason of it?

I make test nodejs app and you can see it on github
https://github.com/devdemi/notifier-cluster
I tried to open 4 browser window and logged with 2 different users.
I publish to redis channel 7 messages and each socket receive this 7 messages. So I have 4 sockets then nodejs get 21 messages. I think it's bad but I have no idea how to write code better. Please advice.

```
> Chanel[notifier-message]:21kxiNqfupovXAgnpH7o: get message 101==101
> Sent message [notifier-message]:21kxiNqfupovXAgnpH7o:
> {"toUserId":101,"message":1390053553752}
> Chanel[notifier-message]:R5hDp02fq3yeX4vupH7p: get message 104==101
> Chanel[notifier-message]:jQllRPNT1TIRn8YhpH7q: get message 101==101
> Sent message [notifier-message]:jQllRPNT1TIRn8YhpH7q:
> {"toUserId":101,"message":1390053553752}
> Chanel[notifier-message]:XTHshkPmN-uTzP6tpH7n: get message 104==101
> Chanel[notifier-message]:21kxiNqfupovXAgnpH7o: get message 101==102
> Chanel[notifier-message]:R5hDp02fq3yeX4vupH7p: get message 104==102
> Chanel[notifier-message]:jQllRPNT1TIRn8YhpH7q: get message 101==102
> Chanel[notifier-message]:XTHshkPmN-uTzP6tpH7n: get message 104==102
> Chanel[notifier-message]:21kxiNqfupovXAgnpH7o: get message 101==103
> Chanel[notifier-message]:R5hDp02fq3yeX4vupH7p: get message 104==103
> Chanel[notifier-message]:jQllRPNT1TIRn8YhpH7q: get message 101==103
> Chanel[notifier-message]:XTHshkPmN-uTzP6tpH7n: get message 104==103
> Chanel[notifier-message]:21kxiNqfupovXAgnpH7o: get message 101==104
> Chanel[notifier-message]:R5hDp02fq3yeX4vupH7p: get message 104==104
> Sent message [notifier-message]:R5hDp02fq3yeX4vupH7p:
> {"toUserId":104,"message":1390053553752}
> Chanel[notifier-message]:jQllRPNT1TIRn8YhpH7q: get message 101==104
> Chanel[notifier-message]:XTHshkPmN-uTzP6tpH7n: get message 104==104
> Sent message [notifier-message]:XTHshkPmN-uTzP6tpH7n:
> {"toUserId":104,"message":1390053553752}
> Chanel[notifier-message]:21kxiNqfupovXAgnpH7o: get message 101==105
> Chanel[notifier-message]:R5hDp02fq3yeX4vupH7p: get message 104==105
> Chanel[notifier-message]:jQllRPNT1TIRn8YhpH7q: get message 101==105
> Chanel[notifier-message]:XTHshkPmN-uTzP6tpH7n: get message 104==105
> Chanel[notifier-message]:21kxiNqfupovXAgnpH7o: get message 101==106
> Chanel[notifier-message]:R5hDp02fq3yeX4vupH7p: get message 104==106
> Chanel[notifier-message]:jQllRPNT1TIRn8YhpH7q: get message 101==106
> Chanel[notifier-message]:XTHshkPmN-uTzP6tpH7n: get message 104==106
> Chanel[notifier-message]:21kxiNqfupovXAgnpH7o: get message 101==107
> Chanel[notifier-message]:R5hDp02fq3yeX4vupH7p: get message 104==107
> Chanel[notifier-message]:jQllRPNT1TIRn8YhpH7q: get message 101==107
> Chanel[notifier-message]:XTHshkPmN-uTzP6tpH7n: get message 104==107
```

I read that to avoid warning "client not handshaken client should reconnect" I need to use clusters.
I have next logs after sending 7 messages to redis channel:

```
> Chanel[notifier-message]:LFthahgJCELKAco3sY64:6564:get message
> 101==101 Sent message [notifier-message]:LFthahgJCELKAco3sY64:
> {"toUserId":101,"message":1390054397147}
> Chanel[notifier-message]:xyZU162eAZQBz0YEsY65:6565:get message
> 101==101 Sent message [notifier-message]:xyZU162eAZQBz0YEsY65:
> {"toUserId":101,"message":1390054397147}
> Chanel[notifier-message]:OU5RrgvoyDyuu7lOsY63:6564:get message
> 102==101 Chanel[notifier-message]:G4J0aXzhRRLWxidOsY66:6564:get
> message 102==101
> Chanel[notifier-message]:LFthahgJCELKAco3sY64:6564:get message
> 101==102 Chanel[notifier-message]:OU5RrgvoyDyuu7lOsY63:6564:get
> message 102==102
> Chanel[notifier-message]:xyZU162eAZQBz0YEsY65:6565:get message
> 101==102 Sent message [notifier-message]:OU5RrgvoyDyuu7lOsY63:
> {"toUserId":102,"message":1390054397148}
> Chanel[notifier-message]:xyZU162eAZQBz0YEsY65:6565:get message
> 101==103 Chanel[notifier-message]:xyZU162eAZQBz0YEsY65:6565:get
> message 101==104
> Chanel[notifier-message]:G4J0aXzhRRLWxidOsY66:6564:get message
> 102==102 Chanel[notifier-message]:xyZU162eAZQBz0YEsY65:6565:get
> message 101==105 Sent message [notifier-message]:G4J0aXzhRRLWxidOsY66:
> {"toUserId":102,"message":1390054397148}
> Chanel[notifier-message]:xyZU162eAZQBz0YEsY65:6565:get message
> 101==106 Chanel[notifier-message]:xyZU162eAZQBz0YEsY65:6565:get
> message 101==107
> Chanel[notifier-message]:LFthahgJCELKAco3sY64:6564:get message
> 101==103 Chanel[notifier-message]:OU5RrgvoyDyuu7lOsY63:6564:get
> message 102==103
> Chanel[notifier-message]:G4J0aXzhRRLWxidOsY66:6564:get message
> 102==103 Chanel[notifier-message]:LFthahgJCELKAco3sY64:6564:get
> message 101==104
> Chanel[notifier-message]:OU5RrgvoyDyuu7lOsY63:6564:get message
> 102==104 Chanel[notifier-message]:G4J0aXzhRRLWxidOsY66:6564:get
> message 102==104
> Chanel[notifier-message]:LFthahgJCELKAco3sY64:6564:get message
> 101==105 Chanel[notifier-message]:OU5RrgvoyDyuu7lOsY63:6564:get
> message 102==105
> Chanel[notifier-message]:G4J0aXzhRRLWxidOsY66:6564:get message
> 102==105 Chanel[notifier-message]:LFthahgJCELKAco3sY64:6564:get
> message 101==106
> Chanel[notifier-message]:OU5RrgvoyDyuu7lOsY63:6564:get message
> 102==106 Chanel[notifier-message]:G4J0aXzhRRLWxidOsY66:6564:get
> message 102==106
> Chanel[notifier-message]:LFthahgJCELKAco3sY64:6564:get message
> 101==107 Chanel[notifier-message]:OU5RrgvoyDyuu7lOsY63:6564:get
> message 102==107
> Chanel[notifier-message]:G4J0aXzhRRLWxidOsY66:6564:get message
> 102==107
```

I started it on my laptop with intel core i5 cpu with 4 cores. When I use 2 core its works fine. But I use 4 core I get messages:

> warn  - client not handshaken client should reconnect

Please explain how clusters works exactly? And What do I need to avoid this warnings?

Answer (score 0):

Now I use RedisStore

```
io.set('store', new RedisStore({
  redis    : redis
, redisPub : pub
, redisSub : sub
, redisClient : client
}));
```

And socket.io saves handshaken data into Redis. After this I receive

> warn - client not handshaken client should reconnect

only when I restart application but I think it should be after restarting.
And it works well with clusters.